# How to get post id of static front page?

Tags: wp-query, homepage

I'm trying to use the front page as a default of sorts for featured images (if no featured image is set, I want to use the front page's, for example)

But I'm having trouble finding out how to get the post ID of the front page in a safe manner (so that my code still works when the front page is inevitably changed by someone)

I know I could just hard code an ID in my code, but that'll break when someone decides to use a new content item as the front page.

Would I have to use wp-query to achieve this? And if so, what is a safe way to achieve this with wp-query?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

WordPress has a few useful options. You can get the homepage ID by using the following:

```
$frontpage_id = get_option( 'page_on_front' );
```

or the blog ID by using:

```
$blog_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
```

[Here's a list of many useful `get_option` parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference).

Comment: `get_option(...)` will return the id as STRING, if you want it to be an INTEGER => do (fastest) direct type cast `(int)` => eg.: `$frontpage_id = (int)get_option( 'page_on_front' );`

Answer (score 12):

You should be able to use `$front_page_id = get_option( 'page_on_front' );`

It'll return the ID of the page you're using as your site's front page, or 0 if it hasn't been set.

Codex: [`get_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)